# Динамическое изменение размера эллипса с помощью QSlider

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Есть код, который открывает первый кадр выбранного видео и отображает его на `QGraphicsScene`. На этом кадре можно нарисовать эллипс, нажав на кнопку мыши и установив его размер по осям с помощью ползунков.

**Вопрос**: Как сделать так, чтобы размер эллипса менялся в реальном времени, когда движутся ползунки?

**OFT_MainWindow3.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(917, 740)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 841, 571))
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 700, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(810, 10, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 781, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 700, 331, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 891, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 120, 51, 541))
        self.verticalSlider.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.verticalSlider.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setInvertedAppearance(True)
        self.verticalSlider.setInvertedControls(False)
        self.verticalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.verticalSlider.setTickInterval(5)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName("verticalSlider")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 90, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 660, 781, 41))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickInterval(5)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 670, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Highlight the field area"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
```

**main.py**:

```
import OFT_MainWindow3
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageQt, ImageEnhance
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow3.Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.imageFrame)
        self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.click_OK)
        self.ellipseItem = None
        self.graphicsView.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.verticalSlider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.verticalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.verticalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValueVer)
        
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValueHor)
        
###################################################################################    

    def browse_file(self):
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Choose video OFT") 
        file = str(file[0])
        if file: 
            self.lineEdit.setText(file) 

###################################################################################    

    def changeValueVer(self, value):
        str_value = str(value)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str_value)
        
    def changeValueHor(self, value):
        str_value2 = str(value)
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(str_value2)

################################################################################### 

    def imageFrame(self):
        file = self.lineEdit.text() 
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", image)
        pic = str("frame.jpg")
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.image = QPixmap(pic)
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.image)
        self.scene.addItem(item)
        view = self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        ############### создаем зум ###############
        if (source == self.graphicsView and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                scale = 1.25
            else:
                scale = 0.8
            self.graphicsView.scale(scale, scale)
            return True
        ############## рисуем эллипс ##############
        str_value = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        y_rad = int(str_value) 
        str_value2 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        x_rad = int(str_value2) 
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            for item in self.graphicsView.scene().items(event.scenePos()):
                if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    self.scene.removeItem(self.ellipseItem)
                    self.reference = item 
                    self.ellipseItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(item) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 75))
                    center = item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos()) 
                    x_start = int(center.x()) - x_rad
                    y_start = int(center.y()) - y_rad
                    x_end = int(center.x()) + x_rad
                    y_end = int(center.y()) + y_rad
                    start = QtCore.QPointF(x_start, y_start) 
                    end = QtCore.QPointF(x_end, y_end) 
                    rect = QtCore.QRectF(start, end) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setRect(rect) 
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

###################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я привязал изменение размер эллипса к событию ползунка

```
QEvent::MouseButtonRelease - Mouse release (QMouseEvent).
```

т.е. вы захватили ползунок и переместите его
и при отпускании ползунка будет изменен размер эллипса.

Вы можете привязать изменение размера эллипса к событиям, которые вам нравятся.

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageQt, ImageEnhance
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(917, 740)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 841, 571))
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 700, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(810, 10, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 781, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 700, 331, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 891, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 120, 51, 541))
        self.verticalSlider.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.verticalSlider.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setInvertedAppearance(True)
        self.verticalSlider.setInvertedControls(False)
        self.verticalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.verticalSlider.setTickInterval(5)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName("verticalSlider")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 90, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 660, 781, 41))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickInterval(5)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 670, 51, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Highlight the field area"))
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        
        
#class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, OFT_MainWindow3.Ui_MainWindow):
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.imageFrame)
#?        self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.click_OK)                             # ???
        self.ellipseItem = None
        self.graphicsView.installEventFilter(self)  
        
        self.verticalSlider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.verticalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.verticalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValueVer)
        self.verticalSlider.setValue(70)                                            # +
        
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValueHor)
        self.horizontalSlider.setValue(70)                                           # +
        
        self.horizontalSlider.installEventFilter(self)                               # + !!!
        self.verticalSlider.installEventFilter(self)                                 # + !!!
        
        self.center = QtCore.QPointF(70, 70)                                         # +++
        self._value, self._value = 70, 70                                            # +++
   
    def browse_file(self):
        self.lineEdit.clear()
#        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Choose video OFT") 
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                self, 
                "Choose video OFT",
                './',                                                                # +
                'Files (*.avi *.mp4)'                                                # +
        ) 
        file = str(file[0])
        if file: 
            self.lineEdit.setText(file) 

    def changeValueVer(self, value):
        str_value = str(value)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str_value)
        self._value = value                                                          # +++ 
        
    def changeValueHor(self, value):
        str_value2 = str(value)
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(str_value2)
        self._value2 = value                                                         # +++

    def imageFrame(self):
        file = self.lineEdit.text() 
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", image)
        pic = str("frame.jpg")
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setObjectName("scene") 
        self.image = QPixmap(pic)
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.image)
        self.scene.addItem(item)
        view = self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.installEventFilter(self) 

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        # создаем зум ???
        if (source == self.graphicsView and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                scale = 1.25
            else:
                scale = 0.8
            self.graphicsView.scale(scale, scale)
            return True
            
        
        ############## рисуем эллипс ##############
        str_value = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        y_rad = int(str_value) 
        str_value2 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        x_rad = int(str_value2) 
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
            for item in self.graphicsView.scene().items(event.scenePos()):
                if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    if self.ellipseItem:                                            # +
                        self.scene.removeItem(self.ellipseItem)
                        
                    self.reference = item 
                    self.ellipseItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(item) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 75))
                    self.center = item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
                    x_start = int(self.center.x()) - x_rad
                    y_start = int(self.center.y()) - y_rad
                    x_end = int(self.center.x()) + x_rad
                    y_end = int(self.center.y()) + y_rad
                    start = QtCore.QPointF(x_start, y_start) 
                    end = QtCore.QPointF(x_end, y_end) 
                    rect = QtCore.QRectF(start, end) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setRect(rect) 
                    
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                    
        if source == self.horizontalSlider and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease or \
                     self.verticalSlider and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            if not self.graphicsView.scene():
                return True
            for item in self.graphicsView.scene().items():  
                if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
                    if self.ellipseItem:                                
                        self.scene.removeItem(self.ellipseItem)                
                    self.reference = item 
                    self.ellipseItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(item) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0, 75))
                    center = self.center    #item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos()) 
                    x_start = int(center.x()) - self._value2      # x_rad
                    y_start = int(center.y()) - self._value       # y_rad
                    x_end = int(center.x()) + self._value2        # x_rad
                    y_end = int(center.y()) + self._value         # y_rad
                    start = QtCore.QPointF(x_start, y_start) 
                    end = QtCore.QPointF(x_end, y_end) 
                    rect = QtCore.QRectF(start, end) 
                    self.ellipseItem.setRect(rect)            
                    return True
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, извиняюсь за лишние строки (вроде: `self.buttonBox.clicked.connect(self.click_OK)`) - забыл удалить в примере